# How to remove pyspeech windows speech recognition commands?

Tags: python, python-2.7, speech-recognition, speech

How can i remove windows commands from pyspeech windows recognition? For example if i wanted for my program to open up notepad i would say "Open notepad", but then windows will also open up notepad for me too. How can i disable this so that my program is the only one running commands? Thank you

Comment: You will have to switch off the windows voice recognition, either by killing the process or doing it the nice way. But most likely you should just inform the user to do it, instead of hacking at his apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change PySpeech a bit.

Try changing

```
_recognizer = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpSharedRecognizer")

to

_recognizer = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpInprocRecognizer")
```

Comment: I believe so. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for the answer or not but I found it for you!

On line 66 change the code to:

```
_recognizer = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpInProcRecognizer")
_recognizer.AudioInputStream = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpMMAudioIn")
```

And on line 112 change the code to:

```
_ListenerBase = win32com.client.getevents("SAPI.SpInProcRecoContext")
```

This should prevent the windows commands from running while also not showing the widget which comes up. Good luck!